# Can you run an intent or script when your app gets installed on Android?

Tags: android

RPM for instance has %post, %postun, %pre, %preun that allow you to write scripts that run during different phases of the install process. I'd like to do things like create and populate a db when my Android apps get installed.

Ted

Answer (score 3):

No, sorry, this is explicitly not supported.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you get to that is doing things on first run, then setting a flag so that you know they've been run.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but you can register a broadcast for TIME_TICK which will gets called every minute. Do the job on the first received broadcast, then discard all future broadcasts.

Edit: CommonsWare's answer is correct, this is just a possible workaround