# How to run a task once, only on installing, on android

Tags: android, adt

I am developing an android application that needs to copy an SQLite database from the assets folder to the data/data/databases directory of the phone.

I call the "copyDB(args[])" method within the "onCreate()" method of the MainActivity.java, but this way it is called everytime you run the application.

I would like to run the "copyDB(args[])" method only once, when installing, reinstalling or updating the application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Store a flag in SharedPreferences, or check if the file exist before you copy it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [android intent when MY app is installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512270/android-intent-when-my-app-is-installed)

Answer (score 2):

For one easy solution, you could use SharedPreferences for this. You store a boolean value that's only true when you've copied all the stuff you wanted, and an integer value with the version code of you app when the copying happened.

You check on every start of your application if the boolean value is false, or it's true but the stored version code differs from the current one (app update happened).

For a more robust solution I'd check in the filesystem if the DB file exists where is should be instead of just relying on a SP boolean.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use SharedPreferences to save a boolean variable. Set it to true when the task is run the first time, then check the variable deciding if you need to run it again.

Answer (score 0):

If running on first launch is soon enough, have a look at [`Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH).